# Independence though ODBC drivers

Tags: jdbc, odbc

Can an application developed with oracle queries in DB layer 
Be run on an SQLServer Database with the help of an ODBC driver

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, if you used only ANSI SQL statements.  ODBC will happily send the text of the query to the query parser on the server and as long as the server can parse it, it will run.

If, however, you have used anything that's specific to Oracle (and that's a long, long list), then it won't work so well.

All that ODBC provides you is abstraction from the connection details -- the driver, the server name, the port numbers etc.

So, how do you get true independence?  Generally, you'll use a query generation library like Hibernate which knows how to translate a query language of some kind (HQL) to the specifics for that particular database (PL/SQL or Transact/SQL).

Comment: So, is it that.. through this drivers... We cant achieve  Query code independence, but can achieve an connectivity to corresponding DB

Comment: Also do we have to change queries syntax too.. in this case of scenarios??

Comment: Yes, and maybe.  The syntax doesn't need to change to support basic queries in odbc, but you might need to do things slightly differently if you need to support stored procedures, prepared statements, or if you use odd features like multiple queries in a single request.  I'm not familar enough with odbc to comment authoritatively, and I've seen some very odd abuse of oracle JDBC...

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Not reliably.

Longer answer: Not through ODBC, but using a [JDBC driver for Microsoft SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) then perhaps if the application was developed only with ANSI standard SQL. Usually, that is not the case and some [PL/SQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/) code will have been used. If an equivalent piece of [T-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) can be written then it is possible to *port* the application. But, to your question, this is largely immaterial to the database connection mechanism.

Addendum: Object Relational Mapping tools usually use *dialects* to generate database independent queries. Other options include using configuration to select the correct queries at run-time (if you need to support both database types).